# Выравнивание повернутого элемента ведется относительно его центра

Tags: html, css

Был текст, я его повернул на -90 градусов и когда пытаюсь выровнять по верхнуму краю то выходит проблема что он выравнивается относительно центра. Понятно что это ибо браузер воспринимает блок все так же горизонтально но отображает контент повернутым. Но есть ли способ это обойти?

https://codepen.io/Telion/pen/aeBxMr

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.main-view {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.colon {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.colon>div {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.colon>div>div {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 9vh;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-view">
  <div class="colon">
    <div>
      <div>COLLABORATOR</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colon">
    <div>
      <div>PROGRAMMER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colon">
    <div>
    <div>DESIGNER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colon">
    <div>
      <div>CREATOR</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-view {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.colon {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.colon>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.colon>div>div {
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-15%);
}

.colon>div>div>div {
  margin: 0.7em 0;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 9vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-view">
  <div class="colon">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>COLLABORATOR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colon">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>PROGRAMMER</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colon">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>DESIGNER</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colon">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>CREATOR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Так? Свойство `transform-origin` в помощь

Comment: Нужно что б текст шел от верхней границы. Для этого там свойство `align-self: flex-start;`.

Comment: @Telion, вроде получилось :)